# Redirect stderr to console and file

Tags: bash, shell, stderr

How can i redirect sdterr of bash script to console and file?
I am using:

```
exec 2>> myfile
```

to log It to myfile. How to extend it to log to console as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fifo

```
$ mknod mypipe p
```

let tee read from the fifo. It writes to stdout and the file you specified

```
$ tee myfile <mypipe &
[1] 17121
```

now run the command and pipe stderr to the fifo

```
$ ls kkk 2>mypipe 
ls: cannot access kkk: No such file or directory
[1]+  Done                    tee myfile < mypipe
```

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
exec 2>&1 | tee myfile
```

Comment: that writes stdout to myfile as well

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `tail -f`

```
$ touch myfile
$ tail -f myfile &
$ command 2>myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open that file by another command (like cat) in background.

```
exec 2>> myfile
cat myfile & >&2
CAT_PID=$!
... # your script
kill $CAT_PID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output to a process and use `tee` in that process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec 2> >( tee -a err.log )

echo bla >&2
```

Comment: this redirects stderr to stdout

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash solution which builts upon [@mpapis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885285/2566213):

```
exec 2> >( while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "${line}" >&2; printf '%s\n' "${line}" >> err.log; done )
```

and expanded:

```
exec 2> >(
    while read -r line; do
      printf '%s\n' "${line}" >&2
      printf '%s\n' "${line}" >> err.log
    done
  )
```